# Question about pawn moves

Tags: sorry

In the board game "Sorry!", can I use a 7 card split moving one pawn 6 spaces around the board and 1 pawn 1 space from "Start"?

Answer (score 4):

No you may not use a 7 card to move a pawn from start as only a 1 or two card can do that.

[Rules](https://www.hasbro.com/common/instruct/Sorry.PDF)

> 7: Either move one pawn forward 7 spaces -- Or split the forward move between any two pawns. Notes 1. You may not use a 7 to start a pawn. 2. if you use a 7 to get a pawn home you muse be able to use the balance of the move for another pawn.